# How does compiler allocate memory for Class Objects?

Tags: objective-c, oop, memory-management

Given the following variable declaration,

```
Foo* foo;
```

how is memory actually being allocated?

This is my guess. There are actually two pieces of memory being allocated here.

1. A 32 bit number representing a memory address stored at `foo` [The pointer]. How exactly does the compiler mark or signal that the pointer is actually storing a reference to memory that is of type of `Foo`?
2. A contiguous memory segment that is uninitialized and typed as Foo. How does it know how much memory to allocate? How does it mark the memory segment as being of type `Foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of a pointer like `Foo *` depends on the target platform. On most current Apple platforms, it is 64-bit, but Apple Watch prior to Series 4 is 32-bit.

There are several contexts in which you might write this:

```
Foo *foo;
```

1. You could write this as a global variable, outside of any `@interface` or `@implementation` variable declaration and outside of any function. Then, each time the program is started, it allocates space for one pointer and sets that pointer to nil.
2. You could write this in an `@implementation` variable declaration, like this:

   ```
   @implementation MyObject {
       Foo *foo;
   }
   ```

   In this case, you have declared an instance variable (or “ivar”). Each time the program creates an instance of `MyObject`, the instance includes space for one pointer and sets the pointer to nil.
3. You could write this as a local variable in a function or a method, like this:

   ```
   - (void)doSomething {
       Foo *foo;
   }
   ```

   In this case, you have declared a local variable. Each time the function or method is called, it allocates one pointer in its stack frame and (assuming you compiled with ARC enabled, which is the default) it initializes the pointer to nil.

Note that in all of these cases, `foo` does **not** point to an instance of `Foo`. It points to nil. To make `foo` point to an instance of `Foo`, you must set it to reference to `Foo` that you got from somewhere else. You could get that reference by calling a function or method, like this:

```
- (void)doSomething {
    Foo *foo;
    // foo is nil here.

    foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
    // If [[Foo alloc] init] succeeded, then foo now points to an
    // instance of Foo. If [[Foo alloc] init] returned nil, which
    // indicates failure, then foo is still nil.
}
```

Or you could be passed a `Foo` reference as a function argument:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithFoo:(Foo *)incomingFoo {
    Foo *foo;
    // foo is nil here.

    foo = incomingFoo;
    // foo now points to whatever incomingFoo points to, which should be
    // either an instance of Foo, or nil.
}
```

Or you could get it from some other global, local, or instance variable.

As to “How exactly does the compiler mark or signal that the pointer is actually storing a reference to memory that is of type of `Foo`”: It doesn't. At compile-time, the compiler knows that `foo` should only point to a `Foo` (or nil), and tries to prevent you from assigning it to things that aren't a pointer to `Foo`. For example, the compiler will issue a warning or an error for this:

```
Foo *foo = @"hello";
```

because the compiler knows that an `NSString` is not a `Foo`. (I assume you didn't make `Foo` a `typedef` or subclass of `NSString`.)

However, you can override the compiler's type concerns using a cast:

```
Foo *foo = (Foo *)@"hello";
```

or by using the `id` type:

```
id something = @"hello";
Foo *foo = something;
```

This compiles, and it runs fine until you try to do something with `foo` that an `NSString` doesn't know how to do.

So it's not the compiler that knows “the pointer is actually storing a reference to memory that is of type of `Foo`”.

The Objective-C runtime knows that the pointer is actually storing a reference to a `Foo`. To understand how the runtime tracks the type of an object, you first need to know about the `Foo` class object.

For every Objective-C class in a program, there is, at runtime, one special object called the “class object”. So for `NSObject`, there is a single `NSObject` class object, and for `NSString`, there is a single `NSString` class object, and for `Foo`, there is a single `Foo` class object. Note that in general, a class object is not an instance of itself! That is, the `NSString` class object is not itself an instance of `NSString`, and the `Foo` class object is not itself an instance of `Foo`.

The `Foo` class object knows what makes up an instance of `Foo`:

- The superclass of `Foo` (maybe `NSObject`, maybe something else).
- The name, type, and size of each instance variable of a `Foo` (except those inherited from the super class of `Foo`).
- The name, type signature, and implementation address of each message understood by a `Foo` (except those inherited from the superclass of `Foo`).

The first bytes of every Objective-C object contain a pointer to a class object.<sup>1</sup> This pointer is called the `isa` pointer, and it determines the type of the object. When you use the syntax that sends a message to an object, like `[foo length]`, the compiler generates a call to `objc_msgSend`. Recall that in `[foo length]`, the object referenced by `foo` is called the *receiver*. The `objc_msgSend` function uses the `isa` pointer of the receiver to find the receiver's class object. It looks through the class object's table of messages to find the implementation of `length` and jumps to it. If `Foo` doesn't define a `length` message, then `objc_msgSend` looks in `Foo`'s superclass for the message, and so on up the superclass chain.<sup>2</sup>

So, it is this `isa` pointer that determines the type of the object at runtime.

So how does a `Foo` object get allocated? When you say `[[Foo alloc] init]`, that means “send the `alloc` message to the `Foo` class object, and then send the `init` message to whatever comes back from `alloc`”. So the `Foo` class object receives the `alloc` message. But the `Foo` class object probably doesn't implement `alloc` directly. It inherits the `NSObject` implementation of `alloc`.

So `+[NSObject alloc]` actually allocates the memory for a new `Foo`. As you say, it allocates a “contiguous memory segment”, but it is not “uninitialized and typed as `Foo`”. It is **initialized** and type as `Foo`. [The `+[NSObject alloc]` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1571958-alloc?language=objc) says:

> The `isa` instance variable of the new instance is initialized to a data structure that describes the class; memory for all other instance variables is set to 0.

You can look at the implementation [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-723/runtime/NSObject.mm.auto.html). It's the `callAlloc` function. It uses the standard C library function `calloc` to allocate memory, and `calloc` fills the memory to 0. Then it sets the `isa` pointer.

As to “How does it know how much memory to allocate”: remember that each class object knows all of the instance variables of its instances. So to allocate a `Foo`, `+[NSObject alloc]` sums the sizes of all of the instance variables of a `Foo`, plus the sizes of all of the instance variables of `Foo`'s superclass, recursively to the end of the superclass chain. That tells it how many bytes to allocate. Except that it would be too slow to do that every time it allocates an object. So the program pre-computes the instance size for every class object at startup, and `+[NSObject alloc]` looks up the precomputed size of a `Foo` in the `Foo` class object.

---

1. Unless the object is represented as a [tagged pointer](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html), but don't worry about that.
2. If you want to know what happens when `objc_msgSend` reaches the end of the superclass chain without finding an implementation, read [Objective-C Message Forwarding](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-03-27-objective-c-message-forwarding.html).

Comment: Wow. Thank you for that very in depth explanation. I just finished going through it all and it is sooooo beautiful. I love the simplicity of it all. Some follow up questions that I have now that I know that pnters are not actually typed in anyway at all. How is is possible for the program to properly calculate the stride on an array for a primitive data type? e.g. it knows that the stride is 8 for char* baseAddress; and that the stride is 32 for int* baseAddress; when doing an array access like baseAddress[i]. I see that primitive types like char and int aren't classes and have no isa pnter.

Comment: The compiler knows that a `char` is 1 byte and an `int` is 4 bytes, just like it knows a `Foo*` is either 4 or 8 bytes (depending on the target platform).

Answer (score 2):

The line of code you've given doesn't allocate any memory. At most, it moves the stack pointer sufficiently to make room for a one-word value (though after optimization, it may not even do that).

> A 32 bit number representing a memory address stored at foo [The pointer].

By "32 bit number" I assume you mean "a pointer-sized integer" which is 64 bits on most modern processors. This may, if it's not optimized, be aliased to some location on the stack.

> How exactly does the compiler mark or signal that the pointer is actually storing a reference to memory that is of type of Foo?

It doesn't signal this, and it doesn't store a reference to memory that is of any type at all. The above line of code just (at most) makes room for a pointer. In ObjC, at runtime there are no object types. Every pointer to an object is considered `id`. ObjC absolutely does not promise that this represents a "contiguous memory segment" (there are plenty of cases where what you would think of as "the data" is not contiguous). At a deeper level, the processor does not care about "types" at all. There is just memory and pointers (`void *`) to memory. (At a deeper level than that, there isn't even "memory." There's physical RAM, caches, registers, and many other things that are generally abstracted away, even in C. For more on that, see [C is not a Low-Level Language](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=3212479).)

> A contiguous memory segment that is uninitialized and typed as Foo. How does it know how much memory to allocate? How does it mark the memory segment as being of type Foo?

This isn't allocated at all by the above line. If you want to allocate memory for `Foo`, you must call `+[Foo alloc]`. Since it is a class method on `Foo`, it knows how much memory `Foo` requires. Nothing marks that memory of being of any type, and Objective-C does not actually care what type it is. All it cares is that theres a pointer in the right place called the `isa` pointer that it can use to lookup how to dispatch messages via `objc_msgSend`.

There are plenty of cases where something called `*Foo` does not point to a `Foo`. It's very common that the actual thing pointed to is a toll-free-bridged type, which is a data structure for a completely different type (a CF structure) that happens to have an `isa` pointer in the right place so that it can pretend to be an ObjC object. All that is required for the system to work is for things to line up "close enough" that `objc_msgSend` can function. There is no need (or mechanism) for marking memory as being some particular type.